# Setting font size to 13 in Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

The font-size select list in Notepad++ doesn't have an option to set the font size to 13. The options are 10-11-12-14, so while it can be set to 11, how can I set it to 13? Please note that using Ctrl + doesn't help for new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ interface does not allow you to use to set font-size 13, so you'll have to edit the Stylers.xml file manually.

This file is located in `%appdata%\notepad++\stylers.xml`

From the top to bottom you have all your styles, where at the very bottom you have the Global Styles.

At the right of most rows, there's the fontSize="" property.

A fontsize="" means the default is being used. If you change this to fontSize="13" you'll effectively change the size to 13.

So your new config line will look like:

```
<WidgetStyle name="Default Style" styleID="32" fgColor="000000" 
    bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Courier New" fontStyle="0" fontSize="13" />
```

(for reading convenience, I placed an enter, but normally this is one row.)

You do not need to change the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Superstitious developers?

If you want, you can change the setting in the file stylers.xml, either for all files:

```
<WidgetStyle name="Global override" styleID="0" fgColor="FFFF80" bgColor="FF8000" fontName="Consolas" fontStyle="0" fontSize="13" />
```

or for one of the individual 'LexerTypes'.

Comment: LOL! not superstitious, but somehow on my display, 13 Consolas is the best setting for me. :)